# MVC app fails to connect to SQL Server db: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in 'master'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

We are developing a web app using MVC 5, EF 6 & SQL Server 2008. We are trying to deploy it on "ServerX", a test server running Windows Server 2008 R2.  ServerX handles both IIS and the SQL Server.  The app database has already been created on ServerX.

If I run the app in Visual Studio on my dev machine, with the web.config connection string pointed at the database on ServerX, the app works fine, and connects to the db fine.

But when I deploy the web app to ServerX (using the File System deploy method) the app fails to connect to the database.  The app initially loads the page fine, but the first db call it makes raises an error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

For now we are using a SQL Server login in the connection string.  It has db_owner role for the app database.  The connection string specifies the (previously-created) app database as Initial Catalog.  And again, the exact same connection string works fine when the app runs from my dev machine.  There web app loads and pulls data without errors as expected.

Any troubleshooting ideas would be most appreciated. We've been all over the web looking for answers, but nothing has been the answer so far.

Here is the redacted connection string:

```
Data Source=ServerX;Initial Catalog=AppTest;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=AppAdmin;Password=secret;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

In desperation, we also added a snippet of code in the dbcontext constructor method to write to a text file what connection string it was using, and indeed this is the string being used at runtime on the server.

Comment: Can you share the connection string? The simplest answer to me seems like a typo in the latter connection string. Plus, it would be good to see how you're connecting to it. Obviously, block out any sensitive information.

Comment: If your app database already exists, why is any `CREATE DATABASE` being run at all?

Comment: @CharliePugh It's a good thought, and I'll add the string.  But if it was a typo, I don't think that exact same connection string would work when the app is launched on my dev machine.

Comment: @R.Richards I agree!  We have not written any code with the intention of doing so.  I think this is a "convention" feature where it can't find the db so it thinks it should create it for us.  But again I'm unclear why the behavior differs when the app runs on the server versus on my dev machine, using the same connection string.

Comment: That error message just sounds like rights differences on the login / user between the servers. You most likely have much higher security access on your dev machine than one the deployed server.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I've had the same thought. Though I'm not sure exactly what permission needs to be addressed.  Something beyond SQL Server I would think, since that is the one piece that is constant in both cases.

Comment: The error message is tied directly to SQL Server. To debug, try logging into SQL Server Management Studio for the server with your client credentials and see what access you have compared to what you're trying to do via code. IF you can create your database via SSMS with the client credentials (not windows account, the  SQLServer account) you know the credentials work

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I just did that to cover all the bases, and the credentials work..  And the thing is, the same connection string with same credentials (using sql login) causes the app to work fine on my dev machine.

Comment: Well - just because it works on your dev machine does not mean it would work anywhere else unless the login and user is setup the same. But you say you could create the database on the server using `User ID=AppAdmin;Password=secret`? Which rights does the login and user have? `dbcreator`? And no grant/deny permissions are set for the `create database` (etc) principal ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117246/discussion-between-david-korn-and-allan-s-hansen).